# Problems with website when I try to combine multiple javascript files

Tags: javascript, smarty, minify

I'm trying to combine all my js files into a single external file, but when I do this some of the js features of my website stop functioning properly. I'm not sure whats causing the problem... Maybe it's because I'm using smarty? Any nudges in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is way too broad for a good answer. Can you give us some specifics - code, libraries used, error messages?

Answer (score 1):

- check files you using on [jslint](http://www.jslint.com/)
- check that all files have new line at end of files
- if you have unclosed comment block in file this will be fine with separate files, but will break concatenated code